# Adding Qt Dependencies to spec file in rpmbuild

Tags: qt5, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, qtwebengine

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am updating the rpmbuild spec file of an application that now uses Qt.

The packages that I need are the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-essential
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
sudo apt-get qt5-default
sudo apt-get qtwebengine5-dev
```

I know the spec file has "BuildRequires" and "Requires" dependency tags...any help in writing this as well as some examples would be helpful. I have a working spec file I just need to add the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. `spec` files are used to generate `rpm` files. However Ubuntu uses `deb` files.

Supposing you really want to create an rpm; then you need to know this:

**BuildRequires**
these packages are required for **building** the rpm. Typically you will need `build-essential` and the '*-dev` packages for building your application

**Requires**
these packages are required upon installation for your application to work; mostly you don't need your build-tools anymore, but you still need the `qt5-default` for example.

---

PS: on a little side note I might be one of the only people in the world building deb packages using spec files with a special conversion script https://bitbucket.org/klaussfreire/spec2deb/src/default/ but I wouldn't really recommend that.

Comment: Thanks for your response much appreciated. I know that in RHEL they use yum which does not have package names that correspond to apt-get under Ubuntu (example qt5-default called something else in yum)...how can I create a spec file that is compatible to both Ubuntu and RedHat?

Comment: Except for using spec2deb you cannot create a Deb from a spec file, and you need a Deb file on Ubuntu...

Comment: Forget deb...I only want to create an RPM file...I just want to know the Qt dependencies

Comment: I don't really understand. If I understand well; you just need to log in to your redhat system and find the package names of the packages that you need; then add them in the `Requires` section. Supposing you need /some/lib.so ; you can use `rpm -qf /some/lib.so` to know which package owns that file.