# RPM Spec file dependencies with Qt Installer

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04, rpm, specifications

I have developed an application using QWebEngine from an installer which I downloaded from download.qt.io. Since Ubuntu 14.04 only supports up to Qt 5.8 that's the version I installed.

Now my application build has an RPM spec file with "Requires" and "BuildRequires" tags where packages are added for dependencies:

Example:

```
BuildRequires: build-essential

Requires: qt5-default 
Requires: qt5webengine5-dev
```

Since I'm installing Qt using an installer how do I indicate this in "BuildRequires" or "Requires" since there are no packages associated with this. The installer just places the needed include and libraries in /opt/Qt5.8.0 which I find and point to in my Makefile. Is there a way to indicate this in RPM? Maybe the library names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Qt Dependencies to spec file in rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432660/adding-qt-dependencies-to-spec-file-in-rpmbuild)

Answer (score 0):

The RPM can only list packages provided by the distro. What those package names are depends on each distro. So it's not very portable. If you're targeting OpenSUSE for example, your RPM needs to use OpenSUSE package names.

If you're looking to provide a download of your application that runs on many distros, you can look into providing an AppImage instead:

https://appimage.org

To create an AppImage of a Qt application, you can use linuxdeployqt:

https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt